# Need to ask for car make in C++ program

Tags: c++

Three cars drive a 500 mile route. Write a program that inputs the car make and the number of gallons of fuel used by each car. After calling a calcMPG() function once for each car, have main determine and display which car was the most fuel efficient and how many miles per gallon it got. The calcMPG() function should be passed the distance driven and the gallons of gas used as arguments, and should return the miles per gallon obtained.  -- Original question, This is what I have completed, I need to add the question of what the make of the car is, where wouuld i add that question for each of the three cars?

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

     float calcMPG(float distInMiles, float gallon)
    {
    return distInMiles / gallon; //return miles per gallon
     }

    int main()
    {
    // Establish variables 
    float distInMiles = 500;
    float effi_c1, effi_c2, effi_c3, gallons; 

    // Ask for car make and amount of gallons used
    cout << " How many gallons of gas did this car use? ";
    cin >> gallons; 
    effi_c1 = calcMPG(distInMiles, gallons); 

    cout << " How many gallons of gas did this car use? ";
    cin >> gallons; 
    effi_c2 = calcMPG(distInMiles, gallons); 

    cout << " How many gallons of gas did this car use? ";
    cin >> gallons; 
    effi_c3 = calcMPG(distInMiles, gallons);


    // Determine which car is most efficent 
    if (effi_c1 > effi_c2) 
    { 
         if (effi_c1 > effi_c3) 
        {
        cout << "car 1 is most efficient.\n";
        cout << "efficiency (in miles per gallons) : " << effi_c1;
        }
        else 
        {
        cout << "car 3 is most efficient.\n";
        cout << "efficiency (in miles per gallons) : " << effi_c3;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if (effi_c2 > effi_c3)
        {
            cout << "car 2 is most efficient.\n";
            cout << "efficiency (in miles per gallons) : " << effi_c2;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "car 3 is most efficient.\n";
            cout << "efficiency (in miles per gallons) : " << effi_c3;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would ask this question before each of the 'how many gallons' questions. That seems the obvious answer. Was there something about this possibility that concerned you?

Comment: right that's what i had thought however when i do that and enter the car make and press enter the program finishes and i cannot enter the gallons question, i supposed i should have added those changes

Comment: This is a well known problem. I'll find a duplicate that explains how you solve it.

Comment: If you have code that is not working it's always a good idea to post it. If the linked duplicate doesn't explain the problem then let me know in the comments here.